# Returning number of items in dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, count

I want to modify this function to return the number of items in the dictionary that begin with each letter. For example:

```
list= ['I', 'say', 'what', 'I', 'mean', 'and', 'I', 'mean', 'what', 'I', 'say']
print(letterCount(list))
{'I': 4, 's': 2, 'w': 2, 'm': 2, 'a': 1}
```

So far I can return the first letter and words, but not the number of letters that are different.

```
def letterCounter(wrdLst):
    output = {}
    for word in wrdLst:
        letter = word[0]
        if letter in output:
            output[letter].append(word)
        else:
            output[letter] = [word]
    return output

list = ["apple", "pear", "brown", "red"]
print(letterCounter(list))
```

this would return the letters instead of number: output:

```
{'I': ['I'], 's': ['say'], 'w': ['what'], 'm': ['mean'], 'a': ['and']}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't append the word, increment a counter.

```
def letterCounter(wrdLst):
    output = {}
    for word in wrdLst:
        letter = word[0]
        if letter in output:
            output[letter] += 1
        else:
            output[letter] = 1
    return output
```

You can also use the standard `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter

def letterCounter(wrdLst):
    return Counter(word[0] for word in wrdLst)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are cool using numpy, you can just use its unique function to do what you are trying to do. Below inside of the `np.unique` call, I do a list comprehension to pull the first letter off of each word and make sure it is lowercase. Then the unique function returns the unique starting letters and with `return_counts` enabled gives their number of occurrences.

```
import numpy as np

words = ['I', 'say', 'what', 'I', 'mean', 'and', 'I', 'mean', 'what', 'I', 'say']
unique, counts = np.unique([word[0].lower() for word in words], return_counts=True)

for (val, count) in zip(unique, counts):
    print (val, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `Counter` way:

```
from collections import Counter

def letterCount(words):
    return Counter(next(zip(*words)))

words = ['I', 'say', 'what', 'I', 'mean', 'and', 'I', 'mean', 'what', 'I', 'say']
print(letterCount(words))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a defaultdict will make the code more concise as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def letterCounter(wrdLst):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for w in wrdLst:
        d[w[0]] += 1
    return dict(d) # return a regular dictionary
    
print(letterCounter(['I', 'say', 'what', 'I', 'mean', 'and', 'I', 'mean', 'what', 'I', 'say']))
```

**Output:**

```
{'I': 4, 's': 2, 'w': 2, 'm': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the initial letters to a string and then use str.count() to make the dict:

```
def letter_count(wrdLst):
   s = ''
   for i in wrdLst:
      s += i[0]
   d = {}
   for i in s:
       d[i] = s.count(i)
   return d
```